# Homepage custom recent news

Tags: categories, homepage, exclude, recent-posts

Is there anyway of telling wordpress, by some plugin or whatever, not to show Recent news from Category X, on my home page?

Or I may do it only by modifying the `home.php` code?

Comment: This is a theme issue. Post the code for the page.

Comment: @s_ha_dum thought so, if it's a theme issue I know what I have to do... I was just wondering if there is any alternative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is the default main query, see the example for [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts), which shows how to exclude a category from the main query:

```
function wpa78465_exclude_category( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'cat', '-1,-1347' ); // IDs of categories to exclude
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpa78465_exclude_category' );
```